# PostgreSQL Does disabling FK constraints disable the system trigger while constraint is disabled?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, system

I am new to postgres using version 12.4 currently through version 13.2.

A developer wants to disable system triggers on tables in his application's schema.  He is requesting SUPERUSER which is not allowed in dev/test because implied expectation is that it would be required in prod.

I have researched several sites on how to disable system triggers, and what I found indicates that only SUPERUSER can do that.

What makes sense to me is that is the user disables the foreign key constraint on a table, the system trigger on the parent table will also be disabled for the duration of the time the foreign key is disabled.

Can anyone confirm or refute my assumption.  If confirmed, I can, of course, tell the user that they only need disable all foreign key constraints in the app schema.  If refuted, it appears the logical answer is to drop all fkey constraints, then recreate them after the data load.

Thanks in advance for an accurate explanation.

Comment: A FK constraint uses a system trigger, a non-superuser cannot touch that. In other words the system trigger is the constraint. The options are drop the FK or create a function that uses `SECURITY DEFINER` see [Create Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to run as a superuser and grant `execute` to the non-superuser.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I know that only superuser can disable system triggers that are at the heart of foreign key constraints.  I just want to ensure that I have a good answer for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is implemented by system triggers on both the source and the target table. Disabling triggers on one of the tables will only disable that part of the foreign key constraint that is concerned with modifications of that table.

I would investigate what the developer wants to do. Disabling foreign keys is very dangerous, because it can result in data corruption. I would probably decline the request. As a safe alternative, you can drop the constraint and create it again. Yes, that takes more time, but I would want to check the integrity after the manipulation anyway, and that will take just as much time.

Comment: So disabling the foreign key constraint on the table does not automatically disable the system trigger on the parent table?  I understand disabling foreign keys can allow for data corruption, and I have denied the user's request for superuser capabilities.  However, from your post it sounds like only alternative is to drop and recreate all foreign key ref constraints?  Disabling the foreign key constraint leaves the system trigger on the parent table active?  That seems to be counter intuitive to the purpose of disabling a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for your reply!  humbly, David Riskind

Comment: You can of course disable the system triggers on the parent table. Or set `session_replication_role` to `replica`.

Comment: Don't want to do "session_replication_role" to replica.  So I'll stick with having the app developer drop the foreign keys and recreate them.  Again thank you for educating me on this subject.